# Beautiful Soup 4 confusion

Tags: python

I'm working on a little python program to get into web scraping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

hero = raw_input("Enter Hero Name: ")

url = "http://www.dotahut.com/heroes/" + hero.lower().replace(' ', '_')

#to double check url in case of error
print (url)

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

# find 'weak against' heroes
print('\nWeak Against:\n')
for champ in soup.find(class_='weak-block').find_all(class_='champ-block'):
    print(champ.find(class_='name').get_text())

# find 'strong against' heroes
print('\nStrong Against:\n')
for champ in soup.find(class_='strong').find_all(class_='champ-block'):
    print(champ.find(class_='name').get_text())
```

When I run this progra I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LewisJames\Google Drive\Personal Files\Programming\Python\Dota 2 Counter.py", line 20, in <module>
    for champ in soup.find(class_='weak-block').find_all(class_='champ-block'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

After reading the BS4 documentation and inspecting elements of the website I'm very confused how this isn't working.

I am a begginer BS4 and python so please bear with me, It would be great if you guys could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
for champ in soup.find(class_='weak-block').find_all(class_='champ-block'):
```

Specifically,

```
soup.find(class_='weak-block')
```

returns 'None', so the next step,

```
find_all(class_='champ-block'):
```

has nothing to search, thus it returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: Thanks, after you mentioning that I managed to figure it out. This seemed to fix it:

for champ in soup.find("div", {"class": "weak-block"}).find_all("div", {"class": "champ-block"}):